# AppConfig.__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'app_module'

Tags: python, django

Just running my first app but facing this issue:

```
**AppConfig.__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'app_module'**
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 4.1.2
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
AppConfig.__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'app_module'
Exception Location: \studybud\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\context.py, line 254, in bind_template
Raised during:  base.views.home
```

**views.py**

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def home(request):
    return render(request, 'home.html')
def room(request):
    return render(request, 'room.html')
```

**Settings.py**

```py
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            BASE_DIR / 'templates'
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'base.apps.BaseConfig'
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

**urls.py**

```py
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [

    path ('',views.home, name="home"),
    path ('room/',views.room, name="room"),
]
```

Comment: You need to add your app in settings.py file it's INSTALLED_APPS list.

Answer (score 1):

`'base.apps.BaseConfig'` is included in the wrong spot under templates under `settings.py`.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).